# git --set-upstream-to is ignored and other branches are pushed

Tags: git

Just as my title suggests, when I checkout a new branch and use `git branch -u origin/master`, it does go track origin/master - however, only for `pull`. When I do `push` on the **CURRENT** branch, git goes push my master branch to origin/master. That confuses me in several ways:

1. What does 'track' really mean - I thought it means track for both `push` and `pull`
2. How does `push` work? Up to now I still thought `push` works for the current branch, then why does it push my master branch?
3. How to really set upstream for `push`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship is set up correctly, but git's default push behaviour doesn't care about it. You'll want to set your `push.default` configuration to `simple` or `upstream`.

A push without arguments will do whatever `push.default` says to, which by default means it will try to push all branches with a name that also exists on the remote.

You can check out the git-config documentation on `push.default` to get an overview of the possibilities.

Comment: This default will change in Git 2.0. Then the default will become `simple`.

Comment: Yes, whenever git 2.0 is finally released, that version will have the default changed.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a local branch and it is the time to push on remote for the first time use

```
git push origin your_branch -u
```

to auto track local-remote branch for both pulls and pushes.

Comment: This is the same as setting up upstream - only for `pull` not for `push`